# LINQ select list element based on class property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class (classA) which has a list of another class (classB), which in turn has a list of another class (classC). I would like to retrieve a specific instance of classC when an ID-property matches what I'm searching for. This is what I have at the moment:

```
                ClassC foundC = null;
                foreach (var a in aList)
                {
                    foreach (var b in a.bList)
                    {
                        foreach (var c in b.cList)
                        {
                            if (c.IdProperty == searchId)
                            {
                                foundC = c;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Is it possible to perform this search with Linq instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var c = aList
    .SelectMany(_ => _.bList)
    .SelectMany(_ => _.cList)
    .FirstOrDefault(_ => _.IdProperty == searchId);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var foundC = aList.SelectMany(a => a.bList).SelectMany(b => b.cList).FirstOrDefault(c => c.IdProperty == searchId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested `SelectMany`s + `FirstOrDefault`:

```
ClassC foundC = aList.SelectMany(a => a.bList.SelectMany(ab => ab.cList))
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.IdProperty == searchId);
if(foundC != null)
{
    // found one
}
```